# Dynamic Ambient Occlusion baking in Three.js

Tags: three.js, ammo.js

I'm working on a game engine and editor http://editor.bad.city (nickname is enough to enter) based on Three.js and want to add baking of AO to the textures when a map is loaded in the game.

In a static scene exported from 3ds max AO can be baked to textures before exporting objects. Here the situation is different because objects are being placed in a browser-based editor and that determines proximity of objects and their position on the ground.

What I don't want to do: There are SSAO filters available with Effect Composer, and I used them, but I don't want to add any post processing to the engine to prevent impacting performance.

Baking only once when the level loads is the only way to retain satisfying performance, but I'm not sure where to start.

Update:
I found a starting point here

http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/simplegi/simplegi.htm

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_simple_gi.html

Comment: omg - thats awesome, no idea of how to answer your question tho. I remeber when javascript was first released - come a long way